# Mathcad to Mathematica: finding coil impedance

Tags: physics, code-request

[image: Mathcad example of solving coil impedance]

I am new to Mathematica.

I am trying to figure out how to do the same thing in Mathematica as the image depicts done in Mathcad.

Declaring the variables with units I figured out.

```
U = Quantity[100, "Volts"];
f = Quantity[50, "Hz"];
R1 = Quantity[20, "Ohms"];
L1 = Quantity[0.005, "Henries"];
XL1 = UnitSimplify[2 π f L1]
```

I am stuck on how define Z1 with the angle.

Comment: I don't speak MathCAD; can you translate the image into pseudocode, or explain how to interpret the angle stuff?

Answer (score 2):

You can separate the impedance and phase shift:

```
Z1 = {Sqrt[R1^2 + XL1^2], Quantity[ArcTan[XL1/R1]*(180/Pi), "AngularDegrees"]}
```

> {Quantity[20.0616, "Ohms"], Quantity[4.49078, "AngularDegrees"]}

Current calculation using the impedance part of the `Z1` array using [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html)

```
I1 = UnitSimplify[U/First@Z1]
```

> Quantity[4.98465, "Amperes"]

For fun:

```
Clear[XL1, Z1, R1, L1]

R1 = 20;(*Ohms*)
L1 = 5/1000;(*Henries*)

XL1[freq_] := 2 Pi freq L1

Z1[freq_] := {Sqrt[R1^2 + XL1[freq]^2], ArcTan[XL1[freq]/R1]*(180/Pi)}

LogLogPlot[Z1[f], {f, 50, 1*^5}, AxesOrigin -> {10, 0}, Frame -> True]
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the most convenient way to handle phase angle is using complex numbers 
as phasors. Electrical engineers use J for the imaginary unit; 
Mathematicians use I. Here is an example:

```
In[1]:= u = Quantity[100, "Volts"];

In[2]:= f = Quantity[50., "Hz"];

In[3]:= r1 = Quantity[20., "Ohms"];

In[4]:= l1 = Quantity[0.005, "Henries"];

(* function to calculate reactance of inductor *)

zL[l_, f_] := 2 Pi f l I // UnitSimplify

In[6]:= zL1 = zL[l1, f]

Out[6]= Quantity[(0.  + 1.5708 I), "Ohms"]

In[7]:= (* series circuit *)
z1 = zL1 + r1

Out[7]= Quantity[(20.  + 1.5708 I), "Ohms"]

In[8]:= i1 = u/z1 // UnitSimplify

Out[8]= Quantity[(4.96935  - 0.390292 I), "Amperes"]

In[9]:= (* magnitude of I *)
Abs[i1]

Out[9]= Quantity[4.98465, "Amperes"]

In[10]:= (* phase of I with respect to V in degrees *)
Arg[i1]/Degree

Out[10]= -4.49078
```